# Convert text to number from csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, data-wrangling

I have a csv file called "my_StudentPerformance.csv" shown in the google link below.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bDr9-gywQuVCcfp18JIwoybecTY-VYvP?usp=sharing

I want to convert texts to number in following columns: `math_score`, `reading_score`, and `writing_score`.

```
read_csv("~/datasets/my_StudentsPerformance.csv")
solution <-c("math_score","reading_score","writing_score")
as.numeric(solution)
```

How could I do to convert all the text in these 3 columns to numeric?

Comment: The mentioned file isn't there. Anyway, c("math_score") cannot be converted to numeric because it is not a number. I assume that you want to pass the column names that need to be converted. `mydata <- read.csv("file"); mydata$column <- as.numeric(mydata$column)`

Comment: I may not understand your question: the columns are numeric already. If you need to handle the three columns separately, that can be achieved by `mydata <- read.csv("file"); columnsdata <- mydata[, c("math_score","reading_score","writing_score")]`

Comment: Please add your data or subset of data here itself instead of any other place. Add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: 1) `df <- read_csv("~/datasets/my_StudentsPerformance.csv")` 2) `df[solution] <- lapply(df[solution], as.numeric)`